# Issues with dim in autoencoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

```
# Encoder
input_size = (32*32,)
hidden_size = 10
output_size = 32*32

x = keras.Input(shape=(input_size))

# Encoder
h = layers.Dense(32, input_shape=[1024,], activation='relu')(x)

# Decoder
r = layers.Dense(output_size, input_shape=[32,], activation='sigmoid')(h)

autoencoder = keras.Model(x,r)

#autoencoder = keras.Model(input=x, output=r)
autoencoder.

compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# Early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                   mode='min',
                   verbose=0,
                   patience=10,
                   restore_best_weights=True)

# Train
#print(train_ds[0])
history = autoencoder.fit(train_ds,
                          epochs=50,
                          batch_size=256,
                          shuffle=True,
                          callbacks=[es],
                          validation_data=(val_ds))
```

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_34' (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "dense_49" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (1024,)

Call arguments received by layer 'model_34' (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1024,), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

I have tried setting the input shape directly- I have no idea why this model expect dim=2. I am starting with 2D data, but am reshaping it to [1024,] for the analysis and using a _mapDataset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.